# hibernate search 5.6 relational operators

Tags: hibernate-search

I hope you are well.

I am upgrading my code to hibernate search 5.6 (from 4.2) and am trying to figure out how I can use relational operators within my search.  In HS 4.2 I was able to enter the following text into my html search input field and my BooleanQuery in HS would handle this for me but this doesn't seem to work anymore:

Java AND JEE NOT Oracle AND "Project Manager"

I have seen the documentation about .must(), .should() but these will not do what I am after as I want the actual search phrase to contain these relational operators (AND, OR, NOT, "") - I don't want to have to parse the users input.

Is this no longer supported?

If it is supported can someone please help me with an example.

My code in HS 4.2 which I need to upgrade to 5.6 looks like:

```
    BooleanQuery keywordBooleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    String[] keywordsField = {"title", "description"};
    BooleanClause.Occur[] keywordsFlag = {BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST};
    String[] keywordsClause = {baseSearchCriteria.getKeywords(), baseSearchCriteria.getKeywords()};
    Analyzer analyzer = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().getAnalyzer("customanalyzer");
    if(keywordsClause != null || keywordsClause.length > 0) {
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query keywordQuery = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(LUCENE_VERSION, 
                keywordsClause, keywordsField, keywordsFlag, analyzer);
        keywordBooleanQuery.add(new BooleanClause(keywordQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
    }
    return keywordBooleanQuery;
```

This also allows me to boost on the title field if the keywords appear in that field.

Thank you in advance.

Kaz

Comment: This is a Lucene feature, not a Hibernate Search one, and according to [this unit test](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/branch_5_5/lucene/queryparser/src/test/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/TestMultiFieldQueryParser.java#L146) the "AND" and "OR" operators are still supported in Lucene 5.5 (the version used in Hibernate Search 5.6). What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to work"? What are the exact symptoms?

Comment: Hi, thank you - I had to explicitly import org.apache.lucene.lucene-queryparser for the MultiFieldQueryParser class after adding the maven dep.